# spring-data-neo4j in "Advanced Mapping" mode - How can I read an entity-value without starting a transaction manually?

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

In my JavaEE7-project, I am using spring-data-neo4j standalone in "Advanced Mapping" mode (using spring-aspects). Everything works fine so far: CRUD on entities within a transaction, where the transaction is started manually or via @Transactional-annotation.

In my usecase, my view accesses an entity "directly":

```
// User
@NodeEntity
public class User {

    private String firstName;

    // getter, setter, ...
}

// SessionBean
@SessionScoped
@Named
public class SessionBean {

    @Transactional
    public User getUser() {
         User user = ...;
         System.out.println(user.getFirstName()); // (1) gives firstName-value.
         return user;
    }
}

// sometpl.xhtml
${sessionBean.user.firstName} // (2) gives "null".
```

Somehow, this behavior (difference between (1) and (2)) is wanted, as spring-data-neo4j supposes read-access [only within a transaction](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/programming-model.html).

But I want to have my usecase(2) working (returning the user's firstName, not "null"). Is there any way to achieve this? So let's say, starting transaction automatically in read-access-case? Implicit read-transactions-support?

Comment: Neo4j 2.0 added mandatory read transactions. But I'm not sure why it returns null. What happens if you test your getUser() method w/o transactional? The user entity is not detached automatically

Comment: So it makes more sense to create a vie object within your tx method that contains all data from your users and their relationships

Comment: Removing Transactional at getUser() -> user.getFirstName() returns null.

Btw, adding Transactional to User::getFirstName() solves my problem, too.

Using a view object could be a workaround; anyhow, IMO it would be best to use the entites in the view directly.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround:

Use a RequestScoped bean to start a transaction in "preRenderView" and to close this tx when the bean is destroyed.

**This does not work on ajax-calls!**

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class SpringDataNeo4jHelperBean {

  @Inject
  @Named
  private Neo4jTemplate neoTemplate;

  private Transaction tx;

  @PreDestroy
  public void finishTransaction() {
    if (this.tx != null) {
        this.tx.success();
        this.tx.finish();
    }
  }

  public void startReadOnlyTransaction() {
    if (!this.neoTemplate.getGraphDatabase().transactionIsRunning()) {
        this.tx = this.neoTemplate.getGraphDatabaseService().beginTx();
    }
  }
}
```

In some template, for example s.th. like a central layout.xhtml:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{springDataNeo4jHelperBean.startReadOnlyTransaction()}" />
</f:metadata>
```